# How to cancel Copy Sheet action when continually getting message boxes about named range already existing?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I copied a worksheet into another workbook. Unfortunately, there are about a million named ranges that are identical between the two worksheets. Now I am stuck in an endless loop of saying "Yes" to the message box pictured below for each named range. Is there a way to stop this loop besides force closing excel? (I can't believe excel doesn't just have a "Yes to all" option for this; I've been spamming enter for the last 5 minutes.

Note: I'm not asking for ways to prevent this in the future; I'm looking for ways to get out of this loop now (since I haven't saved my work yet).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To activate a "Yes to all" function is VERY easy (sorry for your previous unnecessary pain!). Press and hold the keystroke combination: "Alt-Y"